# ListView not refreshing fully in Nativescript with Angular

Tags: listview, nativescript

I'm trying to get my ListView to refresh and reload data from a local array. The array gets updated and i can manually refresh the list but I'm wanting it to be automatic. I've been trying to use `@ViewChild("POHeaderLV") poListView: ElementRef;` with `<ListView>this.poListView.nativeElement.refresh();` but the list still doesnt refresh how it should.

And yes, *the array is changed before* I call the refresh function.

Answer (score 4):

You could get the element by using `getViewById` method. Then you should be able to refresh the ListView by using its `refresh()` method. You could also review the attached example below.

`app.component.html`

```
<GridLayout rows="* 50" >
    <ListView id="lvId" row="0" [items]="myItems" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
        <template let-item="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
            <StackLayout [class.odd]="odd" [class.even]="even">
                <Label [text]='"index: " + i'></Label>
                <Label [text]='"[" + item.id +"] " + item.name'></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </template>
    </ListView>
    <Button text="Refresh" (tap)="refresh()"></Button>

</GridLayout>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {Page} from "ui/page"
import {ListView} from "ui/list-view"

class DataItem {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }
}

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {
    public myItems: Array<DataItem>;
    private counter: number;

    constructor(public page:Page ) {
        //........................
    }

    public onItemTap(args) {
        console.log("------------------------ ItemTapped: " + args.index);
    }

    public refresh(){


        //do something
        var listview:ListView=<ListView> this.page.getViewById("lvId");
        listview.refresh();
    }
}
```